# Reporting results when using Holm-Bonferroni or Benjamini-Hochberg

Tags: multiple-comparisons, reporting

Ive submitted a paper in which we have done a lot of correlations (simple bivariate correlations). As Ive understood it, one is not always required to use multiple comparisons corrections on multiple correlations but we chose to do it to avoid spurious results. Reviewer 2 now want us to use a less conservative method and Ive chosen to use the Holm-Bonferroni method or alternatively the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure. NOW TO MY QUESTION: How do I report these correctly in my paper? Im used to just defining the significant p-value in the methods section and then report all statistically significant results.

Was this clear? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many journals dislike the significant/insignificant dichotomy. R has a p.adjust function that might interest you.

Comment: Yes, Im not a big fan either, but thats the way of medical journals I guess... Thank you, currently only using SPSS at the moment but want to learn R when Ive got the time.

Comment: Here: https://physiology.med.cornell.edu/people/banfelder/qbio/resources_2008/1.5_Bonferroni_FDR.pdf you can find a sensible procedure: in the case of the Benjamini-Hochberg method (pages 6-7), starting from the largest p-value and proceeding until a significant one is found; in the case of the Holm method (page 5), starting from the smallest p-value and proceeding until a non-significant one is found. Thus, I would present adjusted p-values using the order implied by the test.

Comment: However, there's also an alternative procedure. For example, here: https://www.statisticshowto.com/benjamini-hochberg-procedure/ and here: https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Applied_Statistics/Book%3A_Biological_Statistics_(McDonald)/06%3A_Multiple_Tests/6.01%3A_Multiple_Comparisons , you can see that it's also possible to show the raw p-values and their related critical values for rejection.